# Two slightly different definitions of wedge product of alternating tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be alternating tensors of order $k$ and $l$ respectively. In some textbooks, their wedge product is defined as
$$
(\alpha \wedge \beta)(v_1, \cdots, v_{k+l}) = \frac{1}{k! l!} \sum_\sigma \text{sgn}(\sigma) \, \alpha(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, v_{\sigma(k)}) \, \beta (v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \cdots, v_{\sigma(k+l)})
$$
where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $1, \cdots, k+l$. But the factor $1 / k! l!$ does not appear in some other textbooks. In both case, the wedge product seems to be distributive, associative, and skew-commutative. Are there some important formulas that depend on the choice of the factor in the definition? Or don't I need to care about the choice at all?

Comment: The $1/k!$ and $1/l!$ are useful because there are permutations that for example fix the numbers $1$ through $k$ but permute $k+1$ to $k+l$ and vice versa. Since either $\beta$ or $\alpha$ are alternating these will all add up to the same contribution, hence there will be a natural factor of $k!$ and $l!$ appearing, which the definition is cancelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes people use $\frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}$ as well. There is no deep difference, what matters is that you are coherent with your notations.

Comment: As I said, there is no deep difference. What usually happens is that when you do computations a convention can be more helpful than another, because some coefficients cancel out. That is it.

Comment: I was just answering the question 'Are there some important formulas that depend on the choice of the factor in the definition?'. I do not understand why this is a problem for you. Everyone here is free to give their own answer. You could just give yours without complaining about mine. The asker votes which one suits him the best.

Comment: Advices are always welcome. My answer is just based on my experience, as all the others. I could say that once I went through a computation where it was useful to have $(k+l)!$ at the numerator, because some terms cancelled. Currently I am reading an article where some of these things crop up and the factor is $\frac{1}{k!l!}$, but this does not simplify my computations at all. To sum up, I would say it is just a problem of convention and might be useful or not, what matters is to be coherent. If your experience is different, fine. The asker will benefit from our points of view.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the factor $k!l!$ and/or $(k+l)!$ appear is because they are $|S_k||S_l|$ and $|S_{k+l}|$ where $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ letters. If I set $\pi_n= \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma)\sigma$ (thought of as an element of the group algebra of $S_n$) then $\sigma.\pi_n = \pi_n.\sigma = \text{sgn}(\sigma).s$, and hence if $f$ is any $n$-linear form on our vector space $V$,
$$
\pi_n(f) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma)\sigma(f),
$$
where $\sigma(f)(v_1,\ldots,v_n) = f(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(n)})$, is an alternating $n$-form on $V$.  If $f$ is already alternating however, $\text{sgn}(\sigma).\sigma(f) = f$ for all $\sigma\in S_n$, so that $\pi_n(f)= n!f$.

The same phenomenon comes up in defining the wedge product: if $f$ and $g$ are alternating $k$- and $l$- forms, then their tensor product $f\otimes g$ is a $(k+l)$-form, but it is not necessarily alternating. However, if $n=k+l$ then the operator $\pi_n$ fixes that, i.e. $\pi_n(f\otimes g)$ is an alternating $n$-form.

But if $\sigma \in S_n$ is of the form $\tau\circ \rho = \rho\circ \tau$ where $\tau(i)=i$ for $i>k$ and $\rho(i)=i$ for $i\leq k$, then (using $\text{sgn}(\sigma) = \text{sgn}(\tau)\text{sgn}(\rho)$)
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\begin{split}
\text{sgn}(\sigma)\sigma(f\otimes g) &= \text{sgn}(\tau\circ\rho)(\tau\circ \rho)(f\otimes g) = \text{sgn}(\tau\rho)(\tau(f)\otimes \rho'(g)) \\
&= (\text{sgn}(\tau)\tau(f))\otimes (\text{sgn}(\rho)\rho(g)) \\
\end{split}
$$
where $\rho'\in S_l$ is given by $\rho'(i) = \rho(i+k)-k$. Thus if $f$ and $g$ are alternating, it follows $\text{sgn}(\sigma)(f\otimes g) = f\otimes g$.

Now the permutations $\sigma$ of this form are precisely the subgroup $S_{k,l}$ of permutations which preserve the set $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ (and hence necessarily also preserve the subset $\{1,\ldots k\}^c = \{k+1,\ldots,k+l\}$). If $\sigma \in S_{k,l}$ as above, then $\sigma \mapsto (\tau,\rho') \in S_k\times S_l$ gives an isomorphism between $S_{k,l}$ and $S_k\times S_l$.

Thus if we pick $T_{k,l}$ a transversal for $S_{k,l}\leq S_n$, that is, $T_{k,l}\subseteq S_n$ and for each coset $S_{k,l}\sigma$ there is exactly one $t \in T_{k,l}$ with $t\in \sigma S_{k,l}$, that is, $tS_{k,l} =\sigma S_{k,l}$, then if we set $\eta(T_{k,l}) = \sum_{t \in T_{k,l}} \text{sgn}(t)t$ it follows that $\pi_n = \eta(T_{k,l})\pi_k.\pi_l'$ where $\pi_l'$ is $\sum_{\rho\in S_l} \text{sgn}(\rho)\rho_k$ with $\rho_k(i)=i$ if $i\leq k$ and $\rho_k(i) = \rho(i-k)+k$ if $i\geq k+1$.
$$
\pi_n(f\otimes g) = \sum_{t \in T_{k,l}} \text{sgn}(t)t(\pi_k(f)\otimes \pi_l(g))=k!l!\sum_{t\in T_{k,l}} \text{sgn}(t)t(f\otimes g).
$$

Now there are natural choices for the transversal $T_{k,l}$ coming from the ordering on $\{1,\ldots,k+l\}$: every $S_{k,l}$-coset has a unique element $t$ with $t(1)<t(2)<\ldots t(k)$ and $t(k+1)<\ldots<t(k+l)$. Such a permutation is called a $(k,l)$-*shuffle*, and if I write $\mathcal T_{k,l}$ for the set of $(k,l)$-shuffles in $S_{k+l}$, and let $\eta_{k,l} = \eta(\mathcal T_{k,l})$ then $\eta_{k,l}(f\otimes g) = \frac{1}{k!l!}\pi_n(f\otimes g)$.

One reason you might care about this is that if you want to define an algebra structure on alternating forms for $V$ a vector space over a field $\mathsf k$ of positive characteristic, then although $\pi_n$ makes sense over any field, so that it makes sense to write down $\pi_n(f\otimes g)$, if $\min\{k,l\}\geq p = \text{char}(\mathsf k)$ then $\pi_n(f\otimes g) =0$, so that this formula gives a multiplication on forms which becomes identically zero in degree at least $p$. On the other hand, $(f,g) \mapsto \eta_{k,l}(f\otimes g)$ extends the definition of the wedge product to alternating forms on vector spaces over fields of characteristic $p$ in a way which gives a non-trivial multiplication on all of $\Lambda^*(V) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\dim(V)} \Lambda^k(V)$ the space of alternating forms on $V$ in all degrees.

This gives one reason why the formula with the $1/k!l!$ is "better", namely that it descends to positive characteristic. Personally,  I think the formula in terms of shuffles is the "best" because it makes it clearest what is going on, but in characteristic zero, at the end of the day you can define $f\wedge g = c_{k,l}\pi_n(f\otimes g)$ for *any* constants $c_{k,l}$ and provided $(k+l)!c_{k,l}c_{k+l,m} = (l+m)!c_{k,l+m}c_{l,m}$ this will give an associative multiplication on alternating forms.

*Aside*: In particular, if you take $c_{k,l}=1$ for all $k,l$ then you get a multiplication which is **not** associative. If $f,g$ and $h$ are $k$,$l$, and $m$-linear respectively and we write $\mathcal T_{k,l,m}$ for the $(k,l,m)$-shuffles in $S_{k+l+m}$ (where that means what you think it means, (*i.e.* $\mathcal T_{k+l,m}\circ \mathcal T_{k,l}$ where $T_{k,l}\subset S_{k+l}\subseteq S_{k+l+m}$) then $(f\wedge g)\wedge h =(k+l)!\sum_{t\in \mathcal T_{k,l,m}} \text{sgn}(t)t(f\otimes g \otimes h)$ while $f\wedge(g\wedge h) = (l+m)!\sum_{t\in \mathcal T_{k,l,m}} \text{sgn}(t)t(f\otimes g \otimes h)$.